# Changing domain using Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: .htaccess, google-search-console

I'm changing a domain name from webstock.dk to storebuddy.dk

I changed the .htaccess of webstock.dk to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.storebuddy.dk/$1 [R=301,L]:
```

I'm using Google Webmaster Tools to let Google know that domain name has been changed.

However, at 2nd step I get the error "The old site redirects to webstock.dk, which does not correspond to the new site you chose."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you previously added and verified storebuddy.dk in webmaster tools so you can indicate in the change of address tool the new website. 
Use this rule in .htaccess file instead of the one above:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webstock.dk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.webstock.dk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://storebuddy.dk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]